# Nothing happens when a button is clicked in an android application

Tags: android, sqlite, onclick

I am developing an android application using java. I made the database using SQLite. I am trying to check if values got inserted into the database. But when the register button is clicked it is supposed to show a message saying success. But nothing happens and i don't get any errors. I have checked the button ID and I have checked the code a several times but I don't see why the "Success" message is not being displayed. Please help

```
    ---------------Class that Creates the Database------------------------------

    package com.android.disasterAlertApp;
    import android.content.*;
    import android.database.SQLException;
    import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
    import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory;
    import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
    import android.util.*;

    public class DBAdapter {


    //Table where registration details will be saved
    public static final String KEY_USERNO = "userID";
    public static final String KEY_FIRSTNAME = "first_Name";
    public static final String KEY_LASTNAME = "last_Name";
    public static final String KEY_EMAIL = "email";
    public static final String KEY_MOBILENUMBER = "mobile_Number";
    public static final String KEY_LOCATIONUM = "locationID";

    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "DisasterAlertDB";
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
    private static final String DATABASE_TABLE = "User";

    private DbHelper ourhelper;
    private final Context ourContext;
    private SQLiteDatabase ourDatabase; 



    public static class DbHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper{

    public DbHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE" + DATABASE_TABLE + " ("+ KEY_USERNO + "INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " + KEY_FIRSTNAME + "TEXT NOT NULL, " + KEY_LASTNAME + "TEXT NOT NULL, " + KEY_EMAIL + "TEXT NOT NULL, " + KEY_MOBILENUMBER + "TEXT NOT NULL, " + KEY_LOCATIONUM + "TEXT NOT NULL);");
       }

        @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS" + DATABASE_TABLE);
        }

        public DBAdapter(Context c){
        ourContext = c;
    }

       public DBAdapter open() throws SQLException{
        ourhelper = new DbHelper(ourContext);
        ourDatabase = ourhelper.getWritableDatabase();
        return this; 
    }
       public void close(){
        ourhelper.close();
    }
       public long createEntry(String fname, String lname, String email,
        String number, String loc) {
    ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
    cv.put(KEY_FIRSTNAME, fname);
    cv.put(KEY_LASTNAME, lname);
    cv.put(KEY_EMAIL, email);
    cv.put(KEY_MOBILENUMBER, number);
    cv.put(KEY_LOCATIONUM, loc);

    return ourDatabase.insert(DATABASE_TABLE, null, cv);
    }
}
```

---

```
------Class that gets the values from text fields and passes them to create a record-------

    package com.android.disasterAlertApp;

    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.app.Dialog;
    import android.content.DialogInterface;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
    import android.widget.Button;
    import android.widget.EditText;
    import android.widget.TextView;
    import android.widget.Toast;

    public class Registration extends Activity implements OnClickListener{
        Button sqlRegister;
        EditText sqlFirstName,sqlLastName,sqlEmail,sqlMobileNumber,sqlCurrentLocation,sqlUsername,sqlPassword;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.registration);
        sqlFirstName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etFname);
        sqlLastName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etLname);
        sqlEmail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etEmail);
        sqlMobileNumber = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etPhone);
        sqlCurrentLocation = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etCurrentLoc);
        sqlUsername = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etUsername);
        sqlPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etPwd);

        sqlRegister = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bRegister);
        sqlRegister.setOnClickListener(this);
    }
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
        switch (arg0.getId()){
        case R.id.bRegister:
            boolean worked = true;
            try{
            String fname = sqlFirstName.getText().toString();
            String Lname = sqlLastName.getText().toString();
            String email = sqlEmail.getText().toString();
            String number = sqlMobileNumber.getText().toString();
            String loc = sqlCurrentLocation.getText().toString();
            String uname = sqlUsername.getText().toString();
            String pwd = sqlPassword.getText().toString();

            DBAdapter entry = new DBAdapter(Registration.this); 
            entry.open();
            entry.createEntry(fname,Lname,email,number,loc);
            entry.close();
            }catch(Exception e){
                worked=false;
            }finally{
                if(worked){ //Gets fired when values are inserted
                    Dialog d = new Dialog(this);
                    d.setTitle("works");
                    TextView tv = new TextView(this);
                    tv.setText("Success");
                    d.setContentView(tv);
                    d.show();
                }
            }
            break;
            }
        }

      }

 ------------------Modified OnClick Method-------------------------------

public void onClick(View arg0) {
    Toast.makeText(this, "fire", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    switch (arg0.getId()){
    case R.id.bRegister:
        boolean worked = true;
        try{
        String fname = sqlFirstName.getText().toString();
        String Lname = sqlLastName.getText().toString();
        String email = sqlEmail.getText().toString();
        String number = sqlMobileNumber.getText().toString();
        String loc = sqlCurrentLocation.getText().toString();

        DBAdapter entry = new DBAdapter(Registration.this); 
        entry.open();
        entry.createEntry(fname,Lname,email,number,loc);
        entry.close();
        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }finally{
            if(worked){
                Dialog d = new Dialog(this);
                d.setTitle("works");
                TextView tv = new TextView(this);
                tv.setText("Success");
                d.setContentView(tv);
                d.show();
            }
        }
        break;
    }
    }

    }
```

Comment: are you sure `if(worked){ }` is fired ? put `else and check ?`

Comment: What is the path to your Database ? You didn't mentioned any variable above.

Comment: @SALMAN ya i have given it there.                                  DBAdapter entry = new DBAdapter(Registration.this); 
            entry.open();
            entry.createEntry(fname,Lname,email,number,loc);
            entry.close();

Comment: @SamirMangroliya Seems like the OnClick method itself is not getting fired. I can't find whats wrong

Comment: @Sindu_ here `debugging is your friend` check using `System.out.println("calling .....")` in switch statement,try,catch,finally and in if(worked)...

Answer (score 0):

```
}catch(Exception e){
                worked=false;
            }finally{
                if(worked){ //Gets fired when values are inserted
                    Dialog d = new Dialog(this);
                    d.setTitle("works");
                    TextView tv = new TextView(this);
                    tv.setText("Success");
                    d.setContentView(tv);
                    d.show();
                }
            }
```

Its clear from code it will never report error on failure.

Point 1 You are showing message only if worked=true.

Point 2

```
catch(Exception e){
                    worked=false;
                }
```

You should have put e.printStackTrace() here.

Comment: I tried showing a message in the OnClick method after the switch. Even that is not being displayed. Which means that the OnClick method is not being fired. What's wrong? Why isn't the OnClick Method being fired?

Answer (score 0):

You certainly have an Exception occuring. 
All exception are catched but no message is logged

```
}catch(Exception e){
            worked=false;
        }
```

The worked boolean must be false so your dialog is not displayed.